# Unable to run downloaded jar (no access to src files)

Tags: java, javafx, jar

My professor gave us an example application to compare with our own work.  When I try to run on the console I get the following errors.

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at Craps.CrapsGameFrame.<init>(CrapsGameFrame.java:150)
        at Craps.CrapsGameFrame.<clinit>(CrapsGameFrame.java:74)
```

I've had similar errors in previous assignments involving javafx and I was able to fix them by making changes to resource pathways or the controller, however I do not have access to the src files for this application.  Is it a bad application or am I doing something wrong?  Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: as far as I can see this is not javafx, this is swing

Comment: Looks like you need to put a file somewhere, but without seeing the code it's hard to tell where. Didn't your professor provide any documentation?

Comment: Maybe talk to your professor or other course members about it? They can probably provide more valuable input compared to us as they are working with the same software.

Comment: Don't worry, friend. If your professor gave you the jar which is not working, you'll be better than her/him very soon.

Comment: @Adelin I'm aware they are different but i'm assuming it's the same bug either way?

Comment: @Federico klez Culloca There are a lot of files so I wouldn't know where to look, but I'm 90% sure everything he does in this class is recycled from 15 yrs ago.

Comment: @Ben My professor hasn't been a lot of help, but I agree it would be a good idea to ask classmates.  It's an online class so I have to figure out the online class discussion tool which I've never used